# Uncaught ReferenceError: toggleNav is not defined at HTMLDivElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

and I can't find the answer, so I added a nav bar and a side menu, but it's not working, should appear slowly when I'm clicking the button, like an animation. If someone know where is the problem PLS help me, I tried to fix it, but I really don't know where is the problem.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbxBq.png)

Down below is the JS, CSS and HTML code for the menu. The button is on top left corner, and when I'm clickin' , look: [idk what to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbxBq.png)

```js
let toggleNavStatus = false;

let toggleNav = function() {
    let getSidebar = document.querySelector(".nav-sidebar");
    let getSidebarUl = document.querySelector(".nav-sidebar ul");
    let getSidebarspan = document.querySelector(".nav-sidebar span");
    let getSideBara = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-sidebar a");

    if (toggleNavStatus === false) {
        getSidebarUl.style.visibility = "visible";
        getSidebar.style.width = "272px";
        getSidebarspan.style.opacity = "0.5";

        let arrayLength = getSideBara.length;
        for (let i=0; i< arrayLength i++) {
            getSideBara[i].style.opacity = "1";
        }

        toggleNavStatus  == true;
    }

    else if (toggleNavStatus  === true) {
        getSidebar.style.width = "50px";
        getSidebarspan.style.opacity = "0.5";

        let arrayLength = getSideBara.length;
        for (let i=0; i< arrayLength i++) {
            getSideBara[i].style.opacity = "0";
        }

        getSidebarUl.style.visibility = "hidden";

        toggleNavStatus  == false;
    }
```

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body{
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    color: #8E8E8E;
    background: #E6E6E6;
}

.nav-main{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #F09726;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.btn_toggle-nav{
    width: 60px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #F09726;
    background-image: url(menu-icon.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.btn_toggle-nav:hover{
    opacity: 0.5;

}

.nav-main ul{
    float: left;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.nav-main ul li{
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 35px;

}

.nav-main ul li a{
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #111;
    font-family: 'Catamaran', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.nav-main ul li a:hover{
    color: white;
}

.nav-sidebar{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 60px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    height: calc(100vh - 60px);
    background-color: #1b1b1b;
    z-index: 1000;
    transition: all 0.3 ease-in-out;
}

.nav-sidebar ul{
    padding-top: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;

}

.nav-sidebar ul li{
    line-height: 60px;
    list-style: none;

}

.nav-sidebar ul li span, .nav-sidebar ul li a{
    display: block;
    height: 60px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-decoration: none; 
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Catamaran', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    white-space: nowrap; 
    opacity: 0; 
    transition: all 0.3 ease-in-out;
}    

.nav-sidebar ul li a:hover{
    background-color: #222;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-main">
      <div class="btn_toggle-nav" onclick="toggleNav()"></div>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">IEȘIRE</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php">IEȘIRE</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php">IEȘIRE</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php">IEȘIRE</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php">IEȘIRE</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php">IEȘIRE</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <aside class="nav-sidebar">
      
      <ul>
        <li><span>IEȘIRE</span></li>
        <li><a href="index.php">IEȘIRdsfffffffffffffE</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php">IEȘIRfaddddE</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php">IEȘIRafsssssssssssssE</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php">IEȘIsaffffffffffffffRE</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php">IEȘIRsfaaadafsdsdE</a></li>
      </ul>

    </aside>
```